# CPU % usage of all pid

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cpu-usage, pid

I can't obtain CPU% usage of all the pid, without know any program names.

I feel I am close to the solution, this is what I've done so far:

```
for line in $(pgrep -f chrome); \
   do echo -n $line" - ";       \ 
   ps -p $line -o %cpu | sed -n 2p | sed 's/ //'; done
```

In this example I obtain only all chrome pid.. in next step I want all executing pid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the `top` command alone.

To order by CPU percentage (descending), you could use `top -o -cpu`

Comment: I guess OP knows about this command.

Comment: There's no basis for this assumption. He didn't mention it once.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use [top](/questions/tagged/top) for some reason, couple of other ways I can think of doing this.

```
> ps -e -o "%p-%C"
```

Or if you wanted to do it in a script, something like (alternatively could just parse [ps](/questions/tagged/ps) again or check `/proc/pid/stat` for cpu usage)

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for line in /proc/+([0-9]); do
  echo -n "${line##*/}- "
  ps -p "${line##*/}" -o %cpu | sed -n 2p | sed 's/ //'
done
```

Where

- `shopt -s extglob` Turns on extended file globing in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)
- `+([0-9])` Matches any files containing 1 or more digits
- `${line##*/}` Strips everything before and including the last `/` character